# mysql-connector works in netbeans ide but not in executable jar file

Tags: java, ant, mysql-connector, noclassdeffounderror, netbeans-15

I'm using win10, openjdk-18.0.2 x64, mysql-connector-j-8.2.0 and Netbeans 15, building with Ant.

When I run from the IDE the SQL pieces are found and run fine.  When I run with my installed java i.e. `java -jar app.jar`  it runs fine.  However I need to deploy this app on boxes that don't have java installed so it needs to run out of the JRE that gets created with the build.  So if I run `appJRE\bin\java -jar app.jar` everything except the SQL methods work fine.

I have multiple jar files in my IDE classpath, and they all work in the executable except for the mysql-connector*.jar.  I get a runtime error when I try to do anything with SQL.  NoClassDefFoundError: on SQLException, DriverManager etc.

I have the mysql-connector*.jar file in my IDE classpath.  And it is in the same dist/lib directory along with all the other jar files that I deploy with the executable.  I've tried using the `-Djava.libraries.path=dist\lib\mysql-connectors-j-8.2.0.jar` switch when launching the executable but that doesn't help.

I tried adding my jar file names to the Manifest (suggested by ChatGPT).  I found that if I added just the mysql jar file name then I get run time errors because none of the other jar files are found.  When I add them all to the manifest, I only get an error for the sql jar.

I've read through all the similar questions on this site but none get me any farther.

If it were a conflict with versions, I would think I'd get an error when running in the IDE, but like I said, that runs fine.  I'm out of ideas.  If you have anything that can get me going I'd appreciate it.

Here's my manifest.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.8
Created-By: 18.0.2+9-61 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
lib/jsch-0.1.55.jar 
lib/javaee-api-8.0.jar 
lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar 
lib/jfreechart-1.5.3.jar 
lib/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: app
```

My app.jar is in the same directory as the lib directory, and the lib directory contains the mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar along with the other jars.  My appJre is also in the same directory

```
12/13/2023  10:24 AM    <DIR>          lib
12/13/2023  08:35 AM         1,471,425 app.jar
12/13/2023  10:24 AM    <DIR>          appJre
```

And I've tried these commands to run it:

```
appJre\bin\java -jar app.jar
appJre\bin\java -cp .:lib/* -jar app.jar
```

The sql jar is recognized if I launch it with my installed java:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

But I need it to work with the deployable Jre.

The only difference between the two VMs that I can see is that my installed VM uses sharing:

Installed VM recognizes the sql classes

```
<installed>java -version
openjdk version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Deployable VM fails to find sql classes

```
appJre\bin\java -version
openjdk version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode)
```

Why do these behave differently?  It's like the SQL library needs something in the SDK which isn't present in the JRE.

And here's a stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
        at controllers.GuiMan.init(GuiMan.java:137)
        at controllers.MainFrame.init(MainFrame.java:181)
        at controllers.MerlinLab.lambda$main$0(MerlinLab.java:43)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: *I've tried using the -Djava.libraries.path=dist\lib\mysql-connectors-j-8.2.0.jar switch* That doesn't exist. How many different jars does the app need? Please show the jar manifest you used containing the classpath you attempted, *posted as code*

Comment: Is MySQL Connector/J listed in the `Class-Path` attribute in the manifest of your JAR? If not, it isn't loaded. If it is, is the MySQL Connector/J JAR in the right location relative to the JAR so it can be loaded?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've updated the post to include the info you requested.

Comment: `java -jar app.jar` would be the obvious command. That would work if `app.class` has no package (has default package) which is not really a good thing. *IF* the jre you want is below that, then: `appJre\bin\java  -jar app.jar`

Comment: Incidentally you can't mix `-jar` and `-cp`. But you could do `java -cp .:lib/*.jar:app.jar app` on a Unix-like OS. The first of those three path elements is probably redundant

Comment: I down loaded new info into my synapses regarding -jar and -cp and can launch the app either way, but still have the sql issue when running it with the deployable Jre (I added more details to the post).  I'm hoping there's something really stupid I'm doing wrong, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Please post (as a comment actually now) the *exact* command line you're using including the prompt

Comment: The actual name of app is Raptor, and the main class is obviously MerlinLab which is in a controllers package, but here you go:    
  `C:\Users\****\Raptor>RaptorJre\bin\java -cp Raptor.jar controllers.MerlinLab`

Comment: Not quite sure why you chose to paraphrase your commands but let's stick now at literal. 
Again, that's a inappropriate command really. That would work when *everything* is in that jar. Since you're prepared to use a classpath there, why don't you use the *real* classpath? `C:\Users\****\Raptor>RaptorJre\bin\java -cp lib/jsch-0.1.55.jar;lib/javaee-api-8.0.jar;lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar;lib/jfreechart-1.5.3.jar;lib/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar;Raptor.jar  controllers.MerlinLab`

Comment: I'd rather not use the class path in the command line and I shouldn't have to since, like you said, everything needed to run should be in the manifest.  I was trying different things.  I ran the exploded command from your comment and it behaves the same way.  The app runs just fine except for the SQL stuff.

Comment: *I ran the exploded command...* Not sure what you mean by that. What happened when you ran the *actual* command? Actually just noticed that those forward slashes should be backslashes so `C:\Users\****\Raptor>RaptorJre\bin\java -cp lib\jsch-0.1.55.jar;lib\javaee-api-8.0.jar;lib\AbsoluteLayout.jar;lib\jfreechart-1.5.3.jar;lib\mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar;Raptor.jar  controllers.MerlinLab` A *long* time since I did something like that on Windows so can't remember if forward\back makes a diff in that context

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter which way the slashes go.   Behaves the same.

Comment: Please post the *full stack trace*